# Javascript, recursive function to read records

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I’m trying to read records that are connected to each other through a column called parent, and the relation can be one or many on both sides.

I tried to do a recursive function, without success. I made it several times too complex and furthermore it was not working very well! Do you know a standard approach for this?

Sample data:

```
id       parent_id

Record1    main
RecordA1   Record1
RecordA2   Record1
RecordB1   RecordA1
RecordC1   RecordB1
```

Initial code I wrote:

```
data.first_parent_id = main_parent_id;
data.categories = [];

function getCategories(parent_id) {
  // -> get data with column parent_id == parent_id input parameter
  data.categories.push({
    id: id,
    parent_id: gr.getValue('parent_id')
  });

  return data.categories;
}

getCategories(data.first_parent_id);
```

I am trying to obtain an object array like this:

```
  obj = {
    id: record1,
    children: [
      {
        id: RecordA1,
        children: [
          id: RecordB1,
          children: [
            id: RecordC1,
            children: [

            ]
          ]
        ]

      },
      {
        id: RecordA2,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: value,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  };
```

Any suggestions/hints?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Any recursive function must handle two cases: (1) when it accesses a childless node, it should pick a value from it, and return; (2) when it accesses a "parent" node, it should do something with the parent value, if any, and combine it with recursively computed value(s) from child(ren). Your function does not seem to do that. Try implementing this scheme, clearly marking both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the structure of `categories` is as follow:

*This approach uses the function `reduce` along with a recursive function to find parents.*

```
//  id          parent_id
var categories = [
  ['Record1'],
  ['RecordA1', 'Record1'],
  ['RecordA2', 'Record1'],
  ['RecordB1', 'RecordA1'],
  ['RecordC1', 'RecordB1']
];
```

```js
//  id          parent_id
var categories = [
  ['Record1'],
  ['RecordA1', 'Record1'],
  ['RecordA2', 'Record1'],
  ['RecordB1', 'RecordA1'],
  ['RecordC1', 'RecordB1']
];

var result = categories.reduce(function (acc, cat) {
  var id = cat[0], parent = cat[1];

  function findParent(obj) {
    if (obj.id === parent) return obj;
    else {
      if (obj.children) {
        for (var c of obj.children) {
          var f = findParent(c);
          if (f) return f;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function getObject() {
    return { id: id, children: [] };
  }

  if (parent) {
    var found = findParent(acc);
    if (found) {
      found.children.push(getObject());
    } else {
      acc = Object.assign(acc, getObject());
    }
  } else {
    acc = getObject();
  };

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ele unfortunately where I am writing in javascript it is not ECMAscript 6... so I can't use =>